# Why won't my code output what it's supposed to? 2D arrays & methods

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {

    public static String getPhoneNumber(String[][] list, String name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i][0].equals(name)) {
                return list[i][1];
            }
        }
        return "-1"; // Handle the case when the name is not found
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numPairs = scnr.nextInt();

        String[][] list = new String[numPairs][2];

        for (int i = 0; i < numPairs; i++) {
            list[i][0] = scnr.next();
            list[i][1] = scnr.next(); 
        }

        String name = scnr.next();

        String phoneNumber = getPhoneNumber(list, name);
        System.out.println("Phone number for " + name + ": " + phoneNumber);
    }
}
```

Input:
3 Joe,123-5432 Linda,983-4123 Frank,867-5309 Frank

my output:
Your program produced no output

Expected output:
Frank: 867-5309

my code gets user input indicating how many pairs there are, then it gets the pairs, and the last input is the name of the phone number i need to output. but for whatever reason it will not output, nothing prints. Is it my method?

Comment: What do you think it does? Why not store the phone numbers as, maybe, `HashMap <String, String>`?

Comment: There is no error on your code, your input is wrong formatted. You shouldn't use  comma when you want 2 strings for a person. You do scnr.next() for name, and also scanner.next() for the phone number. But since you dont add a space after the name, the name become "Joe,123-5432". So if you set your input to ```3 Joe 123-5432 Linda 983-4123 Frank 867-5309 Frank``` it will work as expected. If you want to use comma seperated name-number format, you need to change your code, split after getting the input.

Comment: it's an assignment so I can't control what the input is, and it has to be with a 2D array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... my code gets user input indicating how many pairs there are, then it gets the pairs, and the last input is the name of the phone number i need to output. but for whatever reason it will not output, nothing prints. Is it my method? ..."*

The *[Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html)* class is going to delimit the text by any *[white-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)* character, by default.

Meaning, a comma will be captured as part of the value returned by the *[next](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next())* *method*.
For example, here is *list*, on the third iteration of the *for-loop*.

```
[["Joe,123-5432", "Linda,983-4123"], ["Frank,867-5309", "Frank"], [null, null]]
```

And, you're expecting the following.

```
[["Joe", "123-5432"], ["Linda", "983-4123"], ["Frank", "867-5309"]]
```

There are a few ways to capture the data.

I recommend dividing the text, using the *[String#indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int))*, or *[String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))*, method.

Here is a re-factor, using *indexOf*.
I've included only the portion of your code that I've adjusted.

```java
String s, list[][] = new String[numPairs][2];

for (int i = 0, d; i < numPairs; i++) {
    d = (s = scnr.next()).indexOf(',');
    list[i][0] = s.substring(0, d);
    list[i][1] = s.substring(d + 1);
}
```

And, here is a re-factor, using *split*.

```java
String s[], list[][] = new String[numPairs][2];

for (int i = 0; i < numPairs; i++) {
    s = scnr.next().split(",");
    list[i][0] = s[0];
    list[i][1] = s[1];
}
```

Output

```
3 Joe,123-5432 Linda,983-4123 Frank,867-5309 Frank
Phone number for Frank: 867-5309
```

Answer (score 1):

The central part of your code could be fixed by basing it on something like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numPairs; i++) {
        String pair = scnr.next();
        list[i] = pair.split(",")
    }
```

'next' reads up to the next whitespace, so it gets you name-and-number as one String.  'split' splits that string around the comma, returning (in this case) a 2-element array.

An alternative approach would be to set the Scanner attributes so that it ends a token on whitespace or comma -- see the `useDelimiter` method.  I find that less appealing so have not written it here.  However, there might be specific requirements for the assignment that have not been given here, such as needing to use Scanner to pick out each token.

Answer (score 0):

The way which your program processes the input and the way the input is provided is different.

For your current program, it expects input to be provided like

```bash
3
Joe
123-5432
Linda
983-4123
Frank
867-5309
Frank
```

which outputs

```bash
Phone number for Frank: 867-5309
```

Since the input is fixed by the assignment to be like

```bash
3 Joe,123-5432 Linda,983-4123 Frank,867-5309 Frank
```

(1) You should attempt to separate the inputs into `3`, `Joe,123-5432`, `Linda,983-4123` `Frank,867-5309`, `Frank`. This can be achieved by reading the string and separating by whitespace.

(2) Use the `3` that you read in to initialise the size of the 2D array.

(3) Then, in your for-loop which process the name-number pairs, use a separate using `,` to get eg. `Frank` and `867-5309`. Store these accordingly into your 2D array.

(4) Lastly, using the `Frank` you got in step (1), read from your 2D array and retrieve the number. Print that out in the expected format as indicated by your assignment. (e.g. `<name>: <number>`)