# I wrote java code to create a contact list but it produces no output

Tags: java

This is the assignment I'm working on:
A contact list is a place where you can store a specific contact with other associated information such as a phone number, email address, birthday, etc. Write a program that first takes as input an integer N that represents the number of word pairs in the list to follow. Word pairs consist of a name and a phone number (both strings), separated by a comma. That list is followed by a name, and your program should output the phone number associated with that name. Output "None" if name is not found. Assume that the list will always contain less than 20 word pairs.

Ex: If the input is:

3 Joe,123-5432 Linda,983-4123 Frank,867-5309 Frank
the output is:

867-5309
Your program must define and call the following method. The return value of getPhoneNumber() is the phone number associated with the specific contact name.
public static String getPhoneNumber(String[] nameArr, String[] phoneNumberArr, String contactName, int arraySize)

This is my code that produces no output:

```
type here 
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   
   /* Define your method here */
   public static String getPhoneNumber(String[] nameArr, String[] phoneNumberArr, String contactName, int arraySize) {
        for (int i = 0; i< arraySize; i++) {
            if (nameArr[i].equals(contactName)) {
                return phoneNumberArr[i];
            }
        }
        return "None";
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int numContacts;
      String[] contactNames;
      String[] contactNumbers;
      String userInput;
      String searchName;
      
      numContacts = scnr.nextInt();
      contactNames = new String[numContacts];
      contactNumbers = new String[numContacts];
      
      for (int i = 0; i<numContacts;i++){
          userInput = scnr.nextLine();
          int commaIndex = userInput.indexOf(",");
          contactNames[i]=userInput.substring(0,commaIndex);
          contactNumbers[i]=userInput.substring(commaIndex+1);
      }
      
      
    
      searchName = scnr.nextLine();
      String phoneNumber = getPhoneNumber(contactNames, contactNumbers, searchName, numContacts);
      System.out.println(phoneNumber);
   }
   
}
```

Comment: This you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77550197/why-wont-my-code-output-what-its-supposed-to-2d-arrays-methods/  Or just someone else in your course?

Comment: If your input is all on one line, as it says in the question you posted, then the program falls over very quickly (producing a lot of output - a backtrace) because you call nextLine many times.  If your input is not all on one line, please fix your question so it is accurately reflecting the conditions.

Comment: It must be someone who's professor uses the same program to teach the course. It is in one line and I think that is the issue but I don't know how to read that input properly.

Comment: Look at the other question. It has solved that part.

Comment: They used a 2d array while my professor is requiring us to use to separate arrays.

Comment: All good now, I figured it out. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `scnr.nextInt()` is going to leave a dangling new line character in the buffer, so your next call to `scnr.nextLine()` is going to return an empty `String`/ *"This is my code that produces no output:"* - No, in my testing, it produces an exception